# Recursively Search From Root Looking for Multiple Files Containing a Word

Tags: linux, terminal

I have an issue where I need to find out where a file was stored at that is completely unknown (don't know where it could have been saved nor do I know what file name it was saved under). Is there a command I can run to search through file contents instead and see if the contents contain a certain phrase? I wrote some of the files contents so I know that all the files contain this text at the top of each of the files. "ALWAYS VERIFY THAT THERE IS". Not really concerned if this might take a while to run since a greater concern is finding these files instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`.

```
 find / -type f -size -10000000c -exec grep -l 'ALWAYS VERIFY THAT THERE IS' /dev/null {} + 2>/dev/null
```

will look for files shorter than 10,000,000 characters long for the phrase and print out the names. If you know the files are shorter then adjust accordingly.

This looks for the phrase anywhere in the file, not just at the top. It would be possible to make this faster by restricting the search to the first line.

If you know it was you that saved the file, as you imply, then

```
find / -user FRED -type f -size -10000000c -exec grep -l '...
```

replacing FRED by your user Id will mean less files to search.

Comment: I tried running that first line command in both an empty directory that had no other directories inside it and also from my root and both of them are not finishing executing the command. I would imagine the empty directory one should finish almost instantly?

Comment: If you want to start from the current directory then change the `/` to `.` - the command as written searches everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification